# After installing, can WindowsService read the data from the file exists in the same machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services, exe

I am working on windows service using .NET Core 3. At the time of development I am reading credentials and server url from `xml` file which is there in `D:\` drive of the same machine.

Just I want to know after generating `exe` and installing in machine, will the `exe` able to read the data from the same file?

`xml` file has credentials and server url. Later if I want to change the user we do not need to compile the code just modify `xml` file and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if account under which the service is running will have "read" permission to your file.